# Using Launchy gem gives an error

Tags: ruby, cross-browser, rubygems

I tried using Launchy gem to open up a browser in my CLI App. I get following error message.

```
  xprop: unable to open display '' 
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/launchy-2.4.3/lib/launchy/applications/browser.rb:63:in `browser_cmdline': Unable to find a browser command. If th
  is is unexpected, Please rerun with environment variable LAUNCHY_DEBUG=true or the '-d' commandline option and file a bug at https://github.com/copiou
  sfreetime/launchy/issues/new (Launchy::CommandNotFoundError) 
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/launchy-2.4.3/lib/launchy/applications/browser.rb:67:in `cmd_and_args' 
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/launchy-2.4.3/lib/launchy/applications/browser.rb:78:in `open' 
  from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/launchy-2.4.3/lib/launchy.rb:29:in `open' 
  from /home/himachhag-45739/code/popular-deals-from-slickdeals.net-cli/lib/popular_deals/cli.rb:49:in `open_deal_in_browser' 
  from /home/himachhag-45739/code/popular-deals-from-slickdeals.net-cli/lib/popular_deals/cli.rb:36:in `menu' 
  from /home/himachhag-45739/code/popular-deals-from-slickdeals.net-cli/lib/popular_deals/cli.rb:8:in `call' 
  from ./bin/popular-deals:10:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone know any possible solution?

Comment: Looks like it needs a headless browser if you're not running X.

Comment: Means? What Should I do?

Comment: Which headless browser do you have installed? If you don't know, you might not have one, so that could be the problem.

Comment: @tadman Thank you so much for your help! So, wouldn't it open chrome or firefox?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `browser_cmdline`, but it could be it's not finding them properly or launching them correctly.